# How to use owl carousel using require js in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs, owl-carousel

Anyone can help me out how to use owl carousel using a custom theme by using require js I have downloaded owl carousel zip file from an official website.
I want to use this owl carousel  in my block in admin I have created a custom theme and apply it in all stores using admin.**make an owl carousel using custom theme**

Comment: You can use any of the slider modules available in market

Comment: See this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259904/owl-carousel-is-not-working-in-magento-2/259908#259908

Comment: @ManishJoy I dont know which css and js files should be there in custom theme and call them in my block using require js

Comment: just 'jquery' & 'owlcarousel'

Answer (score 0):

file : - requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        owlcarousel: 'Vendorname_Modulename/js/owl/owl.carousel',
    },
    shim: {
        owlcarousel: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

> .Phtml File need to define class name

```
<ol class="products list classname owl-carousel">

<script type="text/javascript">
require(['owlcarousel'], function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.classname').owlCarousel({
            items:5,
            loop:true,
            dots:true,
            margin: 10,
            nav:true,
            autoplay:true,
            callbacks:false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                   items:2, 
                },
                480:{
                    items:2,
                },
                768:{
                    items:3, 
                },
                1366:{
                    items:5, 
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where to put require js file ?

Comment: In `vendor/module/view/frontend`

Comment: i want to do it using custom theme

Comment: You can have a module along with the theme