# how to add banner slider in magento 2 without using any extention

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, banner-slider

I am new to magento 2 .

can any buddy help me out for this ,

how to add a banner slider in Magento 2 without using any extension.

Answer (score 4):

### Updated Answer

Yes, can do  implement a slider without using any extension

For implement banner, you have to **work at the theme level**.
Download OwlCarousel2 from https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

and I have copied below files

`owl.carousel.min.css` from https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/dist/owl.carousel.js

and `owl.carousel.js`

> ```
> app\design\frontend\{ThemenVendorName}\{ThemeName}\Magento_Theme\web\css\owl.carousel.min.css
>
> app\design\frontend\{ThemenVendorName}\{ThemeName}\Magento_Theme\web\js\owl.carousel.js
> ```

Add **owl.carousel.js** using require js create a js file`app\design\frontend\{ThemenVendorName}\{ThemeName}\Magento_Theme\requirejs-config.js`.

and code of `requirejs-config.js` is

```
    var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            owlcarouselslider: 'Magento_Theme/js/owl.carousel'
        }
    }
};
```

Now, **call creates a phtml `slider.phtml` (`app\design\frontend\{ThemenVendorName}\{ThemeName}\Magento_Theme\templates`) and implement carousel**

and  **phtml code is**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt01.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt02.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt03.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt04.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt05.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt06.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt01.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt02.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt03.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt04.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt05.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/magento23dev/pub/media/catalog/product/l/t/lt06.jpg"/></div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "*": {
    "Magento_Theme/js/custom-slider": {}
  }
}
</script>
```

Create **`custom-slider.js`** from where you can write `owlcarousel.js` parameters. Location: `app/design/frontend/{ThemenVendorName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Theme/web/js/`

**And code**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'owlcarouselslider'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('carousel.init');
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 5
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After that, you need to call this phtml using layout, So create `cms_index_index.xml` at `app\design\frontend\{ThemenVendorName}\{ThemeName}\Magento_Theme\layout`
 using below code:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <head>
>         <css src="Magento_Theme::css/owl.carousel.css" />
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <referenceContainer name="content">
>             <block class="StackExchange\Magento\Block\Slider" name="home.banner" template="Magento_Theme::slider.phtml"
>             after="-"/>
>         </referenceContainer>
>     </body>
> </page>
> ```

After this implementation, you have to do **Static Content deploy properly**.

Check out below blog for the Best way to implement owlcarousel2 is

[Owl carousel is not working in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259904/owl-carousel-is-not-working-in-magento-2)

Comment: Yes thanks bro, need one more help i am getting images one by one how to get in slider??

Comment: Just add image tag  instead of h2 tag

Comment: i am getting images on my home page but its showing all at a time i need in slider