# How to implement owl carousel in luma theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, slider, owl-carousel

The images for the slider should be chosen in the admin panel. I am new to magento. Kindly tell me how to implement owl carousel. I don't want to use free extensions.

I included the css file link in cms_page_view.xml like this->

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Magento_Cms::css/owl.carousel.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="cms_page"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: + for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need specific to luma theme, My suggestion that you do it in module leve.

Add requirejs-config.js file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add owlcarousel js entry:

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'myowl': 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel'
},
 shim: {
    'myowl': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
}
};
```

then add your owl js file in: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/owl.carousel.js`

You need to run frontend deployment command after this.

then you can call owl carousel in any phtml file or js file using this:

```
require(['jquery','myowl'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // the below must be as per your requirement

        $("#owlslider").owlCarousel({
            navigation : true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: false,
            autoplaySpeed: 2000,
            loop: true,
            smartSpeed: 450
          });
    });
});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I am not using custom theme now. I want to apply straight in luma theme. So where is luma theme files located?

Comment: Check my updated answer, this will work in any theme. Even in luma

Comment: Can you give any full tutorial link for this?

Comment: Where I can insert images?

Comment: After integration of owl carousel you can follow owl carousel docs, see owl carousel example here, you can follow this: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

Comment: I followed your answer. But it looks like it not calling the owl carousel. But the images are displaying but slider is not working. What about this one? http://cookie-code.net/magento-2/using-requirejs-in-magento-2-implementing-owl-slider/. It will work in magento 2?

Comment: Is I need to add owl carousal css in web folder?

Comment: There is no difference if you add in separately in module or you add it in theme web directory, both would work. Did you created new module? have you run `upgrade`, `di compile` and deployment command after that?

Comment: I added in theme web directory -> Magento2\vendor\magento\module-cms\view\frontend. I inserted images in cms and given the appropriate id to that. My doubt is that ->is this one ->myowl: 'magento_module-cms/js/owl.carousel' right in requirejs.config.js? I mean giving magento_module-cms? Is that one right?

Comment: Hi everything works now. But the dots and autoplay such kind of things not working despite I gave required things.

Comment: make sure you have used latest version of owl carousel, and share your code in question as well

Comment: I updated the question. Please check now. I am using the latest versions only. But I don't see that CSS file is working.

Comment: I think problem is with this `<css src="Magento_Cms::css/owl.carousel.css" />` Where did you copy `owl.carousel.css` file? please share path to this file

Comment: That css file was included in frontend\web\css folders. So where I can give the link to that css file?

Comment: There is issue where you are including css, can't help you further on this

Comment: Magento is calling 2 jquery at the same time in DOM. Is the problem due to migrate js?

Comment: migration.js would not be the reason, there should be 2 callings of jQuery. you need to search on code and remove one. There should be one jquery in dom. You have figured out a good point (Y)